# how to install oembed to ckeditor

Tags: php, ckeditor, oembed

I want to add embed video in ckeditor.

is this correct?

1. copy the folder into your plugins directory
2. setting /ckeditor/config.js

> CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
> {
> config.extraPlugins = 'oembed';
>
> ```
> config.oembed_maxWidth = '560';
>
> config.oembed_maxHeight = '315';
> ```
>
> };

and include the plugin in the toolbar (how do I do this).

please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also add the button to the toolbar something like this:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraPlugins: 'magicline,oembed,iframe',
    oembed_maxWidth: '560',
    oembed_maxHeight:  '315',
    toolbar: [
        [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'oembed']
    ]
});
```